# Can I use Tkinter (or some other GUI library) to select files and folders at the same time?

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm writing a simple file transfer program in Python using `Tkinter`, and I want to be able to select files and folders at the same time.

As far as I can tell, I can only do one or the other, using:

`tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames()` or `tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory()`.

Is there any library that lets me select both files and folders?

Preferably, I'd like it to return a list of filenames for files in the current directory, and the path of files in directories. Something similar to:

```
["file1.f", "dir1/file2.f", "dir1/dir2/file3.f"] etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like any of the major GUI libraries for Python support this

- PySide/PyQt
- wxWidgets
- pyGTK

I've attached a hack that kind of does what you want.

The buttons toggle between selecting files and selecting directories... It's not the best User Experience, but it works? You might be able to get something similar with other frameworks, but I'm not as familiar with them as I am with PyQT/PySide. This should work in PyQt as well, if you prefer it (for some reason) over PySide.

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import QFileDialog, QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = QMainWindow()
main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
buttons = QHBoxLayout()
main_layout.addLayout(buttons)


def set_directories():
    filedialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.Directory)

def set_files():
    filedialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.AnyFile)

def on_file_selected(file):
    print(file)

set_files_btn = QPushButton("File")
set_files_btn.clicked.connect(set_files)
set_dirs_btn = QPushButton("Directory")
set_dirs_btn.clicked.connect(set_directories)

buttons.addWidget(set_files_btn)
buttons.addWidget(set_dirs_btn)

filedialog = QFileDialog()
main_layout.addWidget(filedialog)


filedialog.fileSelected.connect(on_file_selected)
filedialog.finished.connect(app.exit)
win.setCentralWidget(QWidget(win))
win.centralWidget().setLayout(main_layout)

win.show()
app.exec_()
```